# How do I show todays top search list?

Tags: php, mysql

I owns a website which is doing lots of searches per day. these search results are stored in my MySQL databse. what I want is I want retrieve today's top searches from MySQL limit to 20 and display in my website. how do I do this with PHP & MySQL??

Thanks

Mathew

Comment: Structure of table where result are stored would be helpful. Do you store queries or search parameters as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do something looked like this:

```
$today = date("F j, Y"); // NOTICE, you have to format your date like you have @ database field
$q = " SELECT   search_string_field, count(search_string_field) as count
       FROM     search_results_table 
       WHERE    search_date_field = '$today'
       ORDER BY count DESC
       GROUP BY search_string_field 
       LIMIT 20";
$results = mysql_query($q);
```

and fetch the results after executing query

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to store the time for each search. With that you can query the database (using date ranges and limit) for the popular searches within a time period or you can do it with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

What metric do you have for storing searches. Do you store every search term, or update a number if the term was used more than once?

If you have a number of terms searched

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM searches ORDER BY searched DESC LIMIT 20';
```

But I think you need to give more info... what does your table look like?